# Difference between vim-gtk and vim-gnome

Tags: gnome, gtk, gvim

How are the packages vim-gtk and vim-gnome different from each other? I've tried both and the resulting Gvim feels the same (to me). If there is no difference, why are both packages maintained?

Comment: This question has been expanded here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/281886/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-vim-packages-available-in-ubuntu to include `vim-athena`, `vim-nox` etc

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Both packages provide the same application, but compiled with different dependencies (e.g. vim-gnome depends on libgnome2). Vim-gtk is important only to people who use Kubuntu (or some lightweight desktop environment) and don't want to install GNOME libraries. If you use the standard Ubuntu desktop, the dependencies are already present, and you can safely use vim-gnome. I agree that it could be confusing.

Comment: So then, what is the difference between libgnome and libgtk?

Comment: libgnome2 is dropped from GNOME3. So what will the difference be in gtk3 world of things?

Comment: Seems like vim-gnome still has libgnome2-0 as a dependency, while both vim-gnome and vim-gtk depend on libgtk2.0-0.

Comment: So, what benefits does libgnome bring to vim now?? The added dependency will not be there for no reason?!

Comment: See [GNOME Libraries Overview](http://www.academictutorials.com/gnome/gnome-introduction.asp)

Comment: Are there any speed benefits to a particular GUI package? For example, in opening large (say, 2GB) csv files, does one particular vim win over another? That'd be super-nice to know.