# I can't install vim on my terminal

Tags: vim, gvim

whenever i try to execute vim, the terminal shows this:
The program 'vim' can be found in the following packages:

```
* vim
 * vim-gnome
 * vim-tiny
 * vim-athena
 * vim-gtk
 * vim-nox
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

So I tried what most of my classmates had done, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install vim` but it didn't work.
The terminal shows this message after I entered `sudo apt-get install vim`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package vim is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'vim' has no installation candidate
```

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Are you sure your universe repository is enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Try to do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before installing vim. Sometimes not-upgraded packages mess up installation of others.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim-common
```

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vim-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
PC:~$ vim hello.c
The program 'vim' can be found in the following packages:
 * vim
 * vim-gnome
 * vim-tiny
 * vim-athena
 * vim-gtk
 * vim-nox
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Answer (score 1):

The message tells you that the vim command is available in differently compiled binary package versions. Try `sudo apt-get install vim-gnome`.

askubuntu.com - [Difference between vim-gtk and vim-gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33260/difference-between-vim-gtk-and-vim-gnome)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VimHowto