# gvim produces error when hitting the close window

Tags: gvim

Everytime I close a gvim window with the little x on the window or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. I get the following error and have to hit return to get my command prompt back. Has anyone seen this?

```
(gvim:26639): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type `<invalid>'
```

Comment: That is the complete command prompt, when you close the window that is what you get

Comment: Bug report: [Launchpad bug #1195448](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/1195448).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, `GLib-GObject-WARNING` while running gtk applications in the command line, are normally ignored by developers and demonstrate a poorly written applications. If you report a bug against the package, it would be the best, but don't act surprised if developers ignore or say that *"is ok"* in your bug report.

**TL;dr**: They are *normally safe* to be ignored.

Answer (score 24):

`vim-gnome` has this problem, but `vim-gtk` does not, so this is a quick fix for the problem:

```
sudo apt remove vim-gnome
sudo apt install vim-gtk
```

Comment: It's worth noting that vim-gtk3 (which includes the GNOME3 integration) also doesn't emit this warning

Comment: What is the difference between vim-gnome and vim-gtk3 or vim-gtk3-py2?  Why is vim-gnome the default in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install vim-gtk3`

Comment: @HansDeragon See https://askubuntu.com/questions/33260/difference-between-vim-gtk-and-vim-gnome

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove vim-gnome && sudo apt-get install vim-gtk3`

Answer (score 1):

I found myself caught between the spurious Warning (vim-gnome) or an empty file bug with vim-gtk3. Open an existing file, then try switching to a new file that doesn't exist using

`:e newEmptyFile` => SEGV

So I'm back to using vim-gnome with this hack in my `~/.bash_aliases` to shutup vim-gnome:

```
alias gvim='gvim 2>/dev/null'
```

I'm sure it will get fixed soon and I won't have to keep throwing away all errors because of a persistent spurious warning.

Comment: Perfect 1 minute solution for a rookie like me :) I tried to replace `vim-gnome` with `viw-gtk` or `vim-gtk3`, but still got the error. The alias is an easy solution. Moreover, if I am not wrong, one still can get error by "canceling" the alias with a backslash `\gvim foo.txt` to call the original `\gvim` application

Comment: You _could_ always pipe the stderr to a `grep -v 'cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type'` (or more detailed if you like) and get on with your life, no?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gvim
```

then select `/usr/bin/vim.gtk-py2`